# How to delete merged question?

Tags: discussion, deleted-questions

I asked a question on Ask Ubuntu. Someone flagged it as a duplicate and merged that question with another question.

My question is : [How to find group name and user name](https://askubuntu.com/questions/740730/how-to-find-group-name-and-user-name)

and it was merged with : [What does the name after '@' at terminal prompt mean?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/6114/what-does-the-name-after-at-terminal-prompt-mean)

I got -3 votes for this question. Now I want to delete that question. Is it possible to delete a merged question?

There is no `delete` option present and the `edit` option is disabled.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

From what's been written so far, it looks like the way to delete a merged post is to ask a question on meta, and then a <del>tiny dinosaur</del> mod will kindly delete it for you.

However, for the sake of future readers, what's probably the better way to do this is **flag the post for moderator attention** by clicking the small **flag** link under the post, like so...

[image]

Answer (score 7):

I have deleted your question. Done.

Comment: Thanks for that. But may know the reason that why I'm not able to delete that question/ post ?

Comment: Merged questions are locked. So, voting, editing or deleting the question/post is not possible for normal users.

Comment: Ok, thanks again.